# Cannot import name _uuid_generate_random in heroku django

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I am working on a project which scans user gmail inbox and provides a report. I have deployed it in **heroku** with following specs:

Language: **Python 2.7**

Framework: **Django 1.8**

Task scheduler: **Celery** (**Rabbitmq-bigwig** for broker url)

Now when heroku execute it the celery is not giving me the output. On Heroku push its showing **Collectstatic configuration error**. I have tried using **whitenoise package**

Also tried executing: **heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput**
Still getting the same error.

*$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput* gave the following 
details of the error.

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/app/salesblocker/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .celery import app as celery_app 
File "/app/salesblocker/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
from celery import Celery
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
from celery import five  # noqa
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 153, in <module>
from kombu.utils.compat import OrderedDict  # noqa
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from uuid import UUID, uuid4 as _uuid4, _uuid_generate_random
ImportError: cannot import name _uuid_generate_random
```

I have also tried to rollback heroku commit to previous working commit and cloned that code but on the next commit(changes:removed a media image from the media folder) its showing the same error again.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You are coming across [this issue](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/545), which affects Python 2.7.11 (Kombu is required by Celery).

The issue is fixed in  Kombu 3.0.30.

Comment: The latest version of Kombu should be used by default, but I had `kombu==3.0.20` in my requirements file.

Comment: Unfortunately, version 3.0.30 breaks backwards compatibility with Django<1.7.

Comment: @Cerin you really shouldn't be using Django < 1.8, as you are missing out on security fixes. Django 1.6 has been end of life since April 2015 and Django 1.4 LTS has been end of life since October 2015. If you can't upgrade to kombu 3.0.30, you apply [the fix](https://github.com/celery/kombu/commit/3f13d9797bc1234e51de98f30e94f511cc21390f#diff-1e972757630e9bd21c157a3e4fdf2e2cL19) to an earlier version, or use the hack that mrooney suggests in their answer.

Answer (score 54):

While upgrading kombu is the ideal option, if you are stuck with older dependencies that don't allow for this, placing this at the top of my settings.py worked for me:

```
import uuid
uuid._uuid_generate_random = None
```

This works because _uuid_generate_random was removed [here](https://hg.python.org/releases/2.7.11/rev/24bdc4940e81), and this simply restores the default value. This hack seems reasonable as Kombu only checks this to [work around a bug resolved in 2007](https://github.com/groner/kombu/commit/4237b7785c87edec866af42e33500a7c31e43d4b), and if you need this fix because of a recent Python update, you inherently aren't affected :)

Comment: This is a real time-saver. Before I update an old system, I need to get it to work...

Comment: I had to put it in my project's __init__.py to work

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the issue Alasdair mentioned was responsible for the error. I solved the problem in my project by following [this workflow](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/a-better-pip-workflow) to keep only the essential *requirements-to-freeze.txt* where I list Celery, but not its dependencies like Kombu.

Then, it's enough to upgrade the essential packages and then re-freeze the full list of dependencies with the working Kombu version.

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements-to-freeze.txt
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And test things to make sure the upgrade didn't break something else ;)

Comment: What are the benefits of using `requirements-to-freeze.txt` over `install_requires` in `setup.py`?

Comment: I guess it's maybe possible to use a setup.py file as well. I mostly don't package apps, though – I just use requirements files since Heroku works with them.