# celery kombu unresolved dependencies post python upgrade

Tags: python, django, celery, kombu

I upgraded my ubuntu environment to 16.04 which also upgraded python to 2.7.12
My environment is as below:
1) Celery - 3.1.25
2) Django - 1.6.5
3) Kombu - 3.0.24

I was getting below errors while I tried to start my celery worker:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 20, in 
    from kombu.utils.compat import _detect_environment
ImportError: cannot import name _detect_environment

I went through kombu code base and got the relevant function for _detect_environment and that resolved the issue.

But, second time I hit below exception:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 29, in 
    from celery.five import buffer_t, items, python_2_unicode_compatible, values
ImportError: cannot import name buffer_t

And could not resolve it. I tried along with latest version of kombu but that also did not help.

I know Django is very old but I am scared to upgrade that as it might break other things. It was working fine along with ubuntu 14.04

Any idea?

Comment: It looks like Celery 3.1.25 [requires](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/eb81426d3f83c3141a9c57d1c62a12cc64e29de4) Kombu > 3.0.36. However Kombu 3.0.30 requires [does not support Django < 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198538/cannot-import-name-uuid-generate-random-in-heroku-django/34199367#34199367). If you stick with Django 1.6 (which is out of date and insecure), then you'll find it tricky to find a set of versions that all support each other.

Comment: Thanks @alasdair